# Authentication Required for jqueryrotate.googlecode.com

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that uses this link below, now every time I access the page a dialog box shows up asking for authentication with user name and password. I never had that hapenning before. Is this a bug or something new, has anyone seeing this before, is there a way to fix this?

http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js

Thank you!

Comment: The owner of the repo has set permissions on it to fobid access unless you have the credentials. This is not something you can fix, its down to the repo owner. It will either be temporary or you will have to find a different location for the plugin or use a different one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this behaviour occurs when the script has been deleted or no longer located at that address or permissions deny public access.

I would use a locally hosted copy, if you have one, or a similar script such as `https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.rotate`.

Edit: Found the author of the script your using on Github

`https://github.com/wilq32
https://github.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js`

Comment: Additionally.... Please never host files from project source code:
1. It's unpredictable (like what happened before).
2. If everyones does that project hosting server is flooded with requests...

Answer (score 3):

Just in case - a new webpage for plugin is here: http://jqueryrotate.com/

It's open source project so please don't flood my server and download plugin instead of serving it directly from my server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find library and download local web site folder. :)

I got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Yup the SVN Author for that script changed the access permissions.
You will need to find a new link or download a copy of the plugin and link to it relatively on your site rather than externally linking it.

This same issue hit five of my clients websites today, rather embarrassing for developers and businesses unfortunately... :(